# Multiple unicode like '\u7cfb' with normal string mixed, how to convert to normal text

Tags: go

```
a:="\u5206\u7ec4\u6570\u4e0d\u80fd\u5927\u4e8e20\u4e2a"
fmt.Println(a) // output: 分组数不能大于20个
```

this is a segment of http reponse, I wan to write it to log, in the log it should be "分组数不能大于20个" not "\u5206\u7ec4\u6570\u4e0d\u80fd\u5927\u4e8e20\u4e2a"

pay attention to "\u4e8e20"
"\u4e8e" is chinese character "于",
 
"20" is just the literal number.
how to convert variable a to the output like fmt.Println(a)?

## not just print it out

I found some snippt but encount error with "\u4e8e20", output "分组数不能大于⁎⁎"

```
func u2s(form string) (to string, err error) {
    bs, err := hex.DecodeString(strings.Replace(form, `\u`, ``, -1))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for i, bl, br, r := 0, len(bs), bytes.NewReader(bs), uint16(0); i < bl; i += 2 {
        binary.Read(br, binary.BigEndian, &r)
        to += string(r)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: The value of the variable `a` **is** "分组数不能大于20个". There is literally **nothing** you have to encode/decode/fiddle/replace. All these `\u` are just present in the **source** code and **not** in the value of the variable during runtime. You might find https://blog.golang.org/strings helpful.

Comment: this is a segment of http reponse, I wan to write it to log, in the log it should be "分组数不能大于20个" not  "\u5206\u7ec4\u6570\u4e0d\u80fd\u5927\u4e8e20\u4e2a"

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If and only if the string contains escape sequences and is properly delimted by quotes: Use strconv.Unquote

Comment: @user2352151, you mean that the HTTP payload _literally_ contains a sequence of bytes such as 0x5c ('\'), 0x75 ('u'), 0x53 ('5'), …and so on, so as to form an ASCII string _literally_ reading `\u5206\u7ec4\u6570\u4e0d\u80fd\u5927\u4e8e20\u4e2a`? If yes, then the answer is to use `strconv.Unquote`—as @Volker suggested. If the data is "more broken", and that function won't cut it, you might need to implement a not too complicated state machine for parsing these `\uXXXX` sequences out to Unicode runes.

Answer (score 0):

the http response is

```
{"code":"100001","msg":"\u5206\u7ec4\u6570\u4e0d\u80fd\u5927\u4e8e20\u4e2a","data":{}}
```

the solution is json.Unmarshal then json.Marshal, the "msg" field then human readable
and thank @Volker @Flimzy @kostix, your comment is very helpful

Comment: Ah, a classic case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) then. Please make yourself [familiar with it](http://xyproblem.info/).